# caching on load webView from local file + JS on Mac

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, macos, webview

I have an external folder with html files and JS files. I have a problem to make my webView to work with updated version of this folder. I mean if I change JS file it doesn't takes the updated version and works always with the old version. How do I prevent this "caching"? I'm running the application from Xcode and even after I exit Xcode and relaunch the application it works with old version.

Thanks for help

Comment: Hitting ctrl+F5 should reload without the cache.

Comment: You mean call reload each time on the mainFrame of the webView?, I'm not working with default browser and it's mac, not pc

Comment: I m loading from remote and having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is supposed to disable caching on WebKit:

```
    [[WebPreferences standardPreferences] setCacheModel:WebCacheModelDocumentViewer];
    [[WebPreferences standardPreferences] setUsesPageCache:NO];

    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
    [sharedCache release];
    sharedCache = nil;
```

It helped me anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you never want caching, append the current timestamp the end of the url of your assets.

```
"myJsFile.js?12378127389"
```

This makes the url different every time an causes the cache check to miss, which means it will reload it from disk.

Comment: I'm writing a mac client, that launches local html file with js files. Where am I supposed to add a timestampt? I don't want to change files, it's not something the client is supposed to touch. Please explain.